# Rails, Heroku does not load my lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm working in a new rails app and I created a little utility class in `RAILS_ROOT/lib`. I use this class in one of the controller with a `require`. In local this class is correctly loaded but when I deploy the app on heroku it crashes with:

> LoadError (no such file to load -- MyUtilityClass)

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I found the problem. In my controller I did a 'require "MyUtilityClas" ' and that was working fine locally. On heroku I needed to do a 'require "/lib/my_utility_class.rb" '. Hmmm... I do not really understand why in fact...

Comment: What is the full name of the file? is it /lib/my_utility_class.rb ?

Comment: `lib` should still be on the load path in heroku I think... does your file `my_utility_class.rb` define a `MyUtilityClass` constant?  Rails should pick that up automagically if it does so you shouldn't have to required it manually.

Comment: 5 years later this is still not consistent with my local environment. I found that using `require "/lib/my_class.rb"` did not work locally, but doing `require "my_class.rb"` did work for me locally and on heroku. I just had to add the `.rb` ending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want `require 'my_file_to_require'` assuming you've named your file properly.

Require takes the filename, not the module/class name, so:

```
require 'MyUtilityClass'   # wrong
```

is wrong but

```
require 'my_utility_class'  # correct
```

is correct, again assuming you've stuck to the normal ruby/rails file naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Heroku logs?!

Comment: in the log, I just have the error message: LoadError (no such file to load -- MyUtilityClass)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to restart your app after it's deployed? You can use the following command:

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: I restarted the app but same thing