# Rails 3 - Error after deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, module, heroku

I have an application working in localhost and also heroku. The last time that I pushed the new version to heroku I got an  error during heroku db:migrate and did heroku db:push and everything was ok.

I get the following error when executing the App.
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant AnswersController::Authentication (NameError)

Here is the relevant code

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  include Authentication
  ...
```

Authentication is a module defined in lib:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

module Authentication
...
```

It is working in localhost but not in heroku.
Any help??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `lib` folder to your the `config.auto_load` path in `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Also, take a look at [this link](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/).

Comment: I don't know why it works in development but crashes in heroku =(

Comment: What happens if you run your application locally in production mode?

Comment: What is the filename in which the module is defined? (It should be `authentication.rb`)

Comment: It was Authentication.rb but I changed it to authentication.rb and it didn't worked...

Comment: Sorry, running out of ideas. As a last resort you could try to drop the file into the `app/models` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to create an entire new heroku application

Comment: It worked running my module to the models folder,,, WHY??? Why heroku isn't loading my lib modules????

Comment: From what I've seen so far while googling, there seems to be a weird issue with loading paths on Heroku. There is a similar question to yours on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477431/rails-heroku-does-not-load-my-lib . Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with Heroku. I suggest you contact the Heroku support regarding your issue: http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/support .

Comment: I had tryied what is discussed in that thread. It says to also 'require' the module. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.